# Any open source solutions to visualize box api's json response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, box-api

I am trying to integrate box into my app. I want to show user all of his documents and folders like box does inside my app.

I can get a http response in json format and then use a jquery plugin to create a tree structure. Ofcourse, I would need to parse the json and get the right folder names and id.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I was wondering if there is an open source solution which has this inbuilt.

The only technologies I am using are Java/Spring/ jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know what Box is, but there are plenty of browser extensions for making nifty trees out of JSON.  Is this just for developer use?

Comment: Box is exactly like DropBox, Google Drive, Google docs etc This is for end user. Once he logs in, he should be able to see a visual representation of the folders from his box account.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for an open source solution to display a folder tree in HTML/CSS/JS. There isn't really one specifically for files and folders, but Bootstrap is probably your best bet.

You can probably put something together pretty quickly utilizing tables or lists: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: Hi Sean! I am looking for a JavaScript equivalent of https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_recursiveTreeNodesAdaptor.html   Also is there any library that box provides which I can use to create a file system UI ?